# In Outlook, I cannot jump to the meeting out of the "Decline" response

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I get a "Decline" from a meeting participant, I want to open the meeting itself quickly. Normally there is a button to achieve this, but it is greyed out:
(below the menu, in the "Respond" group, at the top of the rightmost column)

[image: img]

What can I do to make it visible? What can I ask the admin to change?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You have to open the meeting in Calender or in the invitation. The 'decline' message is just an email. I never saw that this option was available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the button your mentioned just like the folloing screenshot?
[image: button]

This button means "Reply with Meeting", When you receive an email message or a task request, you can create a meeting request as a response with one click.
For more information, see: [Respond to an email message with a meeting request](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/respond-to-an-email-message-with-a-meeting-request-b04e0d58-b221-4ffd-9981-26ceb2bef0ae#bkmk_instructions)

So, when you receive a meeting response message, that button is not available.